# replace "<0x00>" in string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I am having a problem with a string that I received after sending the command line containing the `<0x00>` character so how can I remove it from the string?

For example, my var string is:

```
<0x00>
awplus #
```

**output:**

```
awplus #
```

Comment: Question not clear. Please create a jsfiddle and share link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to get your desired output

```js
var string = "<0x00> awplus #";
string = string.replace("<0x00>", '');
string = string.trim();
document.write (string);
```

Comment: sorry ! 0x00 it is not a string but a special character

Comment: It will also repalce in this way

Comment: You should edit the post with what you have done yet. So we can figure it out

Comment: The output I get after sending the command line via telnet server it is of the form <0x00> followed by the string

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `split` function and pass the string value you want to remove and then select the required part. Please note that `split` function returns **array of string** after spliting the original. You must choose the required value from the array.

I've used `trim()` to remove spaces around the resulting value.
Execute the following code in `browser's developer console` and you'll get the output.

```
var str = "<0x00> awplus #";
console.log(str.split('<0x00>')[1].trim());
```

Comment: sorry ! 0x00 it is not a string but a special character

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?